React draft editor with onChange/StateChange
I have a rich text editor that submits a description. On the detailsPage I'm trying to update the fields with a editorToggle, but the textEditor doesn't pass the submitted description from how I am displaying it with ReactMarkDown. I have useState and useEffect working for other info fields. I basically want the save description to be an initial value in the edit modes text editor.
This is the display and the toggle Editor logic.
const [editDescription, setEditDescription] = useState(description);
const [mode, setEditable] = useState("view");

useEffect(() => {
  setEditDescription(description);
}, [ description]);

const toggleEdit = () => {
  setEditable((prevMode) => (prevMode === "view" ? "edit" : "view"));
  setIsLinkActive(!isLinkActive);
};

const handleDescriptionChange = (event: any) => {
  setEditDescription(event.target.value);
};

<div className="text-custom-secondary">
  {mode === "view" ? (
    description && <Markdown>{description}</Markdown>
  ) : (
    <TextEditor
      onChange={(editDescription) => {
        setEditDescription(draftToMarkdown(editDescription));
      }}
    />
  )}
</div>

and this is the textEditor
const Editor = dynamic(
  () => import("react-draft-wysiwyg").then((mod) => mod.Editor),
  { ssr: false },
);

export default forwardRef<Object, EditorProps>(function TextEditor(props, ref) {
  const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(() => {
    const contentState = ContentState.createFromText(
      "This is the default text.",
    );
    return EditorState.createWithContent(contentState);
  });

  const onEditorStateChange = (newEditorState: any) => {
    setEditorState(newEditorState);
  };

  return (
    <Editor
      editorClassName={cn(
        "border-2 border-solid border-custom-primary px-3 min-h-[350px] cursor-text ",
        props.editorClassName,
      )}
      toolbar={{
        options: ["inline", "list", "link", "history"],
        inline: {
          options: ["bold", "italic", "underline"],
        },
      }}
      editorState={editorState} // Pass the editorState prop
      onEditorStateChange={onEditorStateChange} // Handle changes to editorState
      editorRef={(r) => {
        if (typeof ref === "function") {
          ref(r);
        } else if (ref) {
          ref.current = r;
        }
      }}
      {...props}
    />
  );
});

I have a defaultValue but want that value to be the description on the JobDetails page only.

What is the question or issue you face? It seems like you are asking about something to do with a default value or a JobDetails component, but neither are referenced in the code in the post. Can you [edit] to clarify the post and provide clearer details? I also invite you to take the full [tout] and review Help/How to Ask to learn additional tips to improve the quality of your post.

I find the answer shortly after posting this. I needed to change the EditorProps and add an initialContent and use that in the contentState
interface EditorProps {
  initialContent?: string;
  editorClassName?: string;
  onChange?: (editorState: any) => void;
}

export default forwardRef(function TextEditor(
  { initialContent, ...props }: EditorProps,
  ref,
) {
  const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(() => {
    const contentState = initialContent
      ? ContentState.createFromText(initialContent)
      : ContentState.createFromText("");
    return EditorState.createWithContent(contentState);
  });

  const onEditorStateChange = (newEditorState: any) => {
    setEditorState(newEditorState);
  };

